# Get column names from Pivoted Panda Dataframe, without the column name of the original list

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataset:

```
   a        b     c
99-01-11    8   367235
99-01-11    5   419895
99-01-11    1   992194
99-03-23    4   419895
99-04-30    1   992194
99-06-02    9   419895
99-08-08    2   367235
99-08-12    3   419895
99-08-17    10  992194
99-10-22    3   419895
99-12-04    4   992194
00-03-04    2   367235
00-09-29    9   367235
00-09-30    9   367235
```

I changed it to a pivot table using the following code:

```
df = (pd.read_csv('orcs.csv'))

df_wanted = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['c'], columns=['a'], values=['b'])
```

My goal: I am trying to get a list of the column names in the pivot table.  In other words, I am trying to get this:

`['1999-01-11','1999-01-11','1999-01-11','1999-03-23','1999-04-30','1999-06-02','1999-08-08']`

I tried to use this piece of code:

```
y= df_wanted.columns.tolist()
```

But this gives me a list with both the original column name and the pivot's new column name:

```
[('c', '00-03-04'), ('c', '00-09-29'), ('c', '00-09-30'), ('c', '99-01-11'), ('c', '99-03-23'), ('c', '99-04-30'), ('c', '99-06-02'), ('c', '99-08-08'), ('c', '99-08-12'), ('c', '99-08-17'), ('c', '99-10-22'), ('c', '99-12-04')]
```

I tried deleting the 'c' in various ways, such as

```
def remove_values_from_list(the_list, val):
        while val in the_list:
            the_list.remove(val)
remove_values_from_list(y, 'c')
```

but have had no luck.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem?  PS. retaining the order of the list is important, as I am going to use it as an array of `y` values for a line graph.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is first omit `[]` in `pivot_table` for avoid `MultiIndex` in columns and then use `tolist()` with cast to `string`:

```
df_wanted = pd.pivot_table(df,index='c',columns='a',values='b')
#print (df_wanted)

print (df_wanted.columns.astype(str).tolist())
['1999-01-11', '1999-03-23', '1999-04-30', '1999-06-02', '1999-08-08', 
'1999-08-12', '1999-08-17', '1999-10-22', '1999-12-04',
 '2000-03-04', '2000-09-29', '2000-09-30']
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I also appreciate that you answered the question so quickly, and were clear and polite. Thank you for saving my skin.

Comment: Thank you for accepting! Another solution can be select second level of multiindex, but it is more complicated. Nice day!